# Inserting records from datatable into list

Tags: c#, mysql, list

I am using datatable to retrieve 1000 records from mysql database. I want to copy each record as it is to list. But I do not know the exact syntax for that.

Here is the following code I am trying to retrieve:

```
cmdmysql.CommandText = "select * from marctest.spectrum";
conn.Open();

MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdmysql.CommandText, conn);
//MySqlDataReader reader;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataMember = dt.TableName;

// row = dataGridView1.DataSource.ToString();
//row = dt.TableName;
MySqlDataReader reader;
reader = cmdmysql.ExecuteReader();

List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

foreach(DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
{
    mylist.Add(dt.Rows.ToString());
}

textBox1.Text = mylist.ToString();
```

Does anybody have an idea regarding the same? This is my actual code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that doing DataRow.ToString() is going to get you anything useful (most likely just the object type).

If you want the **data** from each row as a string (perhaps tab-delimited?), you can try:

```
foreach(DataRow row1 in dt.Rows) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
      sb.Append(row1[col].ToString();
      sb.Append('\t');
   }
   mylist.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```

This will croak, if any of your column's have a null value so you may want to handle that.

Comment: @nimish-deshpande: If my answer worked/helped, why did you switch the accepted answer?  Also, feel free to hit the up-arrow on *any* answer (or question) on StackOverflow that you find helpful.

Comment: Welcome...Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq to see how thinks work on SO.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru - Why create the sb object inside the first foreach loop? Wouldn't it be better to create it before?

Comment: @AVProgrammer - You are correct...you may save a couple of nanoseconds by creating the StringBuilder outside the loop. Not sure it makes much difference over 1000 records; over 1,000,000? maybe.  I just wanted to keep it simple for the asker.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru - Sure, it just seemed like a no-brainer to me ;)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `dt` is the query result, and If you only need to convert these results to strings, then this should work:

```
foreach(DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
    mylist.Add(row1.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried with the above mentioned solution... but it retruns System.Data.DataRow.Collection in the list.. following is my modified code:
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
            
           foreach(DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
            {
                mylist.Add(dt.Rows.ToString());
            }

Comment: Could you provide the query code in your question, Also you shouldn't accept my answer yet since it didn't work with you :)

Comment: cmdmysql.CommandText = "select * from marctest.spectrum";
             conn.Open();
             MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdmysql.CommandText, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             da.Fill(dt);
             dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
             dataGridView1.DataMember = dt.TableName;
MySqlDataReader reader;
             reader = cmdmysql.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Not here, in your question, edit your question and put it there so every one can see it.